# React-router-dom v6 error: no route match location

Tags: reactjs, authentication, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to build route for an Admin Webpage. I'm using React-Router-Dom v6, ReactJs.

Below is my code:

index.js: (just route code)

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
.
.
.
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.js

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={
          <PrivateRoute>
            <Home/>
          </PrivateRoute>
        }
      />

      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginForm />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home.js  (just code for route):

```
import { Routes, Route,Link} from "react-router-dom";
const { Header, Content, Footer, Sider } = Layout;

function Home() {
  const { Header, Content, Footer, Sider } = Layout;
  const itemLabel = [
    "Dashboard",
    "Quản lý người dùng",
    "Quản lý đơn hàng",
    "Quản lý sản phẩm",
    "Companies",
    "Promotion",
    "Email Template",
    "Postal Code",
  ];

  // define link for route
  const links = [
    "/",
    "/user",
    "/order",
    "/product",
    "/promo",
    "/template",
    "/#",
    "/#",
  ];

  return (
    <Layout hasSider id="components-layout-demo-fixed-sider">
      {/* Route should be wrapper here */}

      {/* left sidebar */}

      <Sider>
        {/* menu of sidebar */}
        <Menu theme="dark" mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={["0"]}>
          {items.map((item, index) => (
            <Menu.Item key={index}>
              <Link to={links[index]}>
                {item.icon} <span>{item.label}</span>
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
          ))}
        </Menu>
      </Sider>

      {/* Main Layout */}
      <Layout>
        {/* Header of page */}
        <AppHeader />

        <Content>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route path="/user" element={<UserManagement />} />
              <Route path="/order" element={<OrderManagement />} />
              <Route path="/product" element={<ProductManagement />} />
              <Route path="/order/detail" element={<OrderDetails />} />
              <Route path="/product/detail" element={<ProductDetails />} />
            </Routes>
        </Content>

        {/* Footer of page */}
        <Footer
          style={{
            textAlign: "center",
          }}
        >
          Hook Shopee Services @2022 created by Mr Tuyen
        </Footer>
      </Layout>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

So my problem is: When i login, it completely redirect to Home page, route is "/" and render Dashboard, everything come true.

[image: Lay out of Dashboard component]

After that when i click 2nd item in sidebar (item that next to and under Dashboard: "Quản lý người dùng"), error occur, url is "/user" but it render nothing. And console warning: No routes matched location "/user"

[image: Error occur]

[image: Prepare to click 2nd item - next to and below Dashboard]

Hope your helps. Thanks so much, and i alway welcome every suggest to refactor my code (i'm new in React-router-dom and not so confident with this code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I see You are using nested routes so you need to call the Outlet component for the place that you want to display those data, but if you are not interested in nested routing just define all of the routes inside your app.js and wrapp your app.js with the layout and other stuffs